# How do I create a resque worker automatically at bootup?

Tags: ruby, redis, passenger, rack, resque

Ok, I'm making my first ruby app. Who know moving everything over to 'production' is so fugging complicated. So far I've struggled my way through configuring passenger, getting it to run on startup, then getting redis to run on startup.

My last task is on startup to add 1 worker. Right now, I have to ssh in and run my rake command `rake workers:start`. Obviously this is no good when I want to close ssh.. so I just dont really know how or what the next step is.

I tried copying resque default config to config.ru and it just blows up Passenger with errors. I also looked into resque-pool which some people mentioned but that is over my head.

all i have to do is add 1 worker on bootup. This isnt that serious of an app so simpler would be best at this point.

Comment: By the way, do you use Rails? Or some other framework?

Comment: Sinatra. sorry, should have mentioned that

Comment: I understand what you feel. I was overwhelmed too :-)

Comment: Honestly I looked at capistrano and it was a nightmare. I havent found any good tutorials.. i bought 2 ruby books and none of them talk about THIS stuff, which is the hard part for me. Ruby is 'easy', sure you just google anything you dont know. But between rack, passenger, rakefile, god, sinatra, and the trillions of different configurations i need to set up its definitely overwhelming. its like i dont even know where to start... especially considering most stuff is for rails

Comment: Yeah, I know. I decided to write a "lightweight" version of my app in Sinatra, but gave up and went back to Rails :-) Hang in there, it gets better :-)

Comment: What made you choose Sinatra? I'm sure it's a great framework, but when you're a complete noob, it's better to choose well-documented and supported path (the "most stuff is for rails" point).

Comment: Errr.. because it was easy :) it was actually really easy up until this point. Now its getting hairy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In production you should be using [god](http://god.rubyforge.org/) to watch your processes. Even if this project is a small one, I strongly recommend investing your time and setting it up.

Another big **a must** is [Capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/Documentation-v2.x).

So, if you were using god, here's a [config file](https://github.com/defunkt/resque/blob/master/examples/god/resque.god) that would help you.

You could also try scheduling `rake resque:work` at system startup, using a proper script in `/etc/init.d/` or `/etc/init/` or another (depends on what system you use). I tried this some time ago and I gave up (don't remember why).

I understand that this my answer isn't exactly what you're looking for right now. But imagine this: if everything is set up, then deploying next version is as easy as running `rake deploy` on your development machine. And it will take care of pulling your code from repository, running migrations, restarting workers and webservers and what not.

Comment: I know this isn't the answer you were expecting but how might I do this with with a 'proper' startup script. I promise Ill look into god and capistrano more but I just want it working first. I'm using centOS.

Comment: Hmm, I'm using ubuntu on my servers. Don't know about centos, sorry.

Comment: For people that believe God is someone to worship, and not something to use, this is an unacceptable solution. A better alternative would be monit.

Answer (score 7):

I don't use the god gem because (1) I've seen a project that was very thrashed by the complexity of setup it introduced, and (2) I'm personally really comfortable with the standard Linux (Ubuntu) tools that handle this kind of thing.

**To start the Resque workers on bootup**

I have this code in my `/etc/rc.local` file. I have a *deploy* user on the system:

```
# Start Resque
su -l deploy -c "/home/deploy/start-resque-workers"
su -l deploy -c "/home/deploy/start-resque-webui"
```

Then, in those scripts I set up the ruby environment and run the rake task:

```
# Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
if [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] ; then
  # First try to load from a user install
  source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
elif [[ -s "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] ; then
  # Then try to load from a root install
  source "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm"
else
  printf "ERROR: An RVM installation was not found.\n"
fi

# Use rvm to switch to the default ruby. 
rvm use default

# Now launch the app
cd /home/deploy/app-name-here/current
nohup rake QUEUE=* RAILS_ENV=production environment resque:work &
```

I've been using this kind of set up for years, and it's solid. The servers don't crash. I don't yet need the overhead of installing another system (like the god gem) to watch over these other servers.

Additionally, I use a capistrano gem to handle restarting the workers on deploy.

Comment: Hey, I see you answered this almost 4 years ago, but...  Would you happen to have a way to clear the resque workers... Using ps ax and killing the pid kills the process, but resque still keeps them registered.

Comment: hmm... I'm sorry, I don't. Here are my resque scripts, if any help: https://github.com/asm-products/think-200/tree/master/script

Comment: Hey thanks for getting back to me! I just implemented this yesterday: https://gist.github.com/jdkealy/a7f817bbb8e568ff38bb 
I was worried about killing a server while the resque workers were busy with a task and adding a symlink to a bash script which executes a rake task in /etc/rc0.d/ seems to quit the workers gracefully!