# Unable to start worker after rake task ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, resque, refinerycms

I have read number of questions here but no one helped me as of yet.

Scenerio: I am starting rake task using button click and it also starts the rake task but the problem is that it does not activate worker.

**Here is my code of button click:**

```
def run_rake_jobs
   Resque.enqueue(ImportJobs)
   puts Resque.info, "**************************************************"
   flash[:notice] = "Importing Jobs Now"
   redirect_to :back
end
```

**Task code:**

```
module Refinery
  module Titans
    class ImportJobs
      @queue = :import_jobs
      def self.perform
        system "rake st:import_jobs"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

How I can start worker? I have tried all possible tricks but did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

The code in your `run_rake_jobs` only enqueues the `ImportJobs` background job into a queue on redis but *does not trigger* its execution. The code in the controller continues without interruption.

To actually run the queued jobs you need to call a separate command (typically outside rails code), such as `rake resque:work`, see the [resque readme](https://github.com/resque/resque#overview) for more info.

This pattern for running background jobs is typical: in your Rails code, you only *enqueue* the jobs that should be run in the background. Then, there is a separate process that fetches the background jobs from the queue and runs them using one or more workers. This way you can decouple long-runnning tasks from your main Rails code.

Comment: Got your point of view but where should I write that piece of code? Any specific place? Basically I want them to work in background without writing `rake resque:work` each time in console.

Comment: The `rake resque:work` is a separate, eternally running process, it polls the queue periodically for new jobs and sleeps otherwise. So, practically you need to run the command in the console just *once* after the server starts. Typically this is done in an init script when the server boots up. You will find many sample init scripts on the internet, and also e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13355187/1544012).

Comment: Ok thats fine. You are right in saying that. So, this is the only way to cope this issue? I dont want to crash my server with bash or init scripts. :)

Comment: Sorry, I'm unaware of another way. But it should not be that hard. The hardest part is ensuring a proper ruby / rails environment if you use rvm. But there are multiple tutorials as well as answers here on SO.

Comment: No problem. :) Can you show some links here please? Thanks.

Comment: If you use rvm, the SO answer linked above should work almost out-of-the-box. You just need to update the path to your application and the RVM to use. Just save the content from the answer to a script, e.g. `run_resque_jobs.sh` give it proper permissions (`chmod a+x run_resque_jobs.rb`) and try to edit it and run until it successfully runs the worker rake. Once you have it correct, just add a call of this script to `/etc/rc.local` or similar place. That's it.

Comment: Fine. Thanks. And Then I need to push that file to my repo? I am having confusion that how it will work on my production. I mean where to place and where to push and all that?

Comment: You may or may not push the script to the repo, it's up to you. It is rather a sysadmin task than rails task. For example we do have our init scripts in the repo but only as a backup, and have them elsewhere (somewhere in `/etc`) on the production server. The preferred init scripts location and usage differ a bit on different OSes so if you are not well versed in server administration, you might ask someone who takes care of your server to install the init script for you.